# Infidelity as distance measure

Tags: quantum-operation, fidelity

Let $\mathcal{X} \in {\rm CP}(\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{K})$ and unital (compositive positive and unital maps). Let $\mathcal{Y} \in {\rm CPT}(\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{K})$(complete positive and trace preserving). We can derive
$$
\langle {\rm id}, \mathcal{Y} \rangle \leq \Vert {\rm id} \Vert_F \Vert \mathcal{Y} \Vert_F \leq d^2,
$$
where the equality holds when ${\rm id}=\mathcal{Y}$ (This can be found in the proof of lemma 48 in [proof of lemma 48](https://journals.aps.org/prxquantum/pdf/10.1103/PRXQuantum.2.010201)). Now we aim to use the above inequality to evaluate
$$
\langle \mathcal{X}, \mathcal{Y} \rangle = \langle {\rm id}, \mathcal{X}^\dagger\circ \mathcal{Y} \rangle \leq d^2,
$$
where the inequality is due to the fact that $\mathcal{X}$ is unital and CP, so $\mathcal{X}^\dagger$ is CPT, then $\mathcal{X}^\dagger \circ \mathcal{Y}$ is CPT. By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, the equality holds when $\mathcal{X}^\dagger \circ \mathcal{Y}={\rm id}$. Also, if we directly use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for $\langle \mathcal{X}, \mathcal{Y} \rangle$, the equality holds when $\mathcal{X}=\mathcal{Y}$. Then we can deduce that $\mathcal{X} = \mathcal{Y}$ is equavalient to $\mathcal{X}^\dagger \circ \mathcal{Y}={\rm id}$. However, it is not generally true. So, what are the problems of these derivations?

Comment: Am I missing something? So $\langle \mathcal{X}, \mathcal{Y}\rangle = \Vert \mathcal{X}\Vert_F \Vert\mathcal{Y}\Vert_F$ when $\mathcal{X} = \mathcal{Y}$, and $\langle \rm{id}, \mathcal{X}^\dagger \circ \mathcal{Y}\rangle = \Vert \rm{id} \Vert_F \Vert \rm{id} \Vert_F$ when $\mathcal{X}^\dagger \circ \mathcal{Y} = \rm{id}$, but these do not both hold unless both conditions are true right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.